# Why does if(not nil) give me an ArgumentError?

Tags: if-statement, null, boolean, elixir

```
defmodule My do
  def go do
    x = nil

    if(not x) do
      IO.puts "hello"
    else
      IO.puts "goodbye"
    end
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
/elixir_programs$ iex c.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> My.go
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    c.exs:5: My.go/0

iex(1)>
```

According to `Programming Elixir >= 1.6`, p.35:

> Elixir has three special values related to Boolean operations: true,
>   false, and nil.  nil is treated as false in Boolean contexts.

It doesn't seem to be true:

```
defmodule My do
  def go do
    x = false

    if (not x) do
      IO.puts "hello"
    else
      IO.puts "goodbye"
    end
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex c.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> My.go       
hello
:ok

iex(2)>
```

Comment: Have you tried switching to cond and seeing if it compiles? Or switching the statements to if x do IO.puts "goodbye" else IO.puts "hello"

Answer (score 4):

```
  @spec not true :: false
  @spec not false :: true
  def not value do
    :erlang.not(value)
  end
```

Elixir 's latest definition of `not` function shows that it only receive `false` and `true`.

However, `nil` is not belongs to them, so it shows `argument error`.

> Elixir has three special values related to Boolean operations: true, false, and nil. nil is treated as false in Boolean contexts.

`nil` is just an `atom`, that is `nil === :nil`.

You can consider using `!` operator, which in fact is `Kernel.!` macro.

> Receives any argument (not just booleans) and returns `true` if the
>   argument   is `false` or `nil`; returns `false` otherwise.

`!nil` will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

"[Kernel.not/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#not/1)" or not/1 expects a Boolean value

> note: Other values different of `nil` and `false` are `true`

try this example:

```
x = nil
if (x) do true else false end
false
```

Examples with short-if condition and true, false, nil values

```
iex> if nil , do: true, else: false
false
iex> if !nil , do: true, else: false
true
iex> if false , do: true, else: false
false
iex> if !false , do: true, else: false
true
iex> if not false , do: true, else: false
true
iex> if true , do: true, else: false
true
iex> if !true , do: true, else: false
false
iex> if not true , do: true, else: false
false
```